# Lavaan: How to free a constraint in one group out of two, while at the same time using effects-coding scaling method?

Tags: lavaan

I am examining differences in latent means between two groups using the following syntax:

```
   smmlanguage<-'

   injury =~ NA*IN1+c(in1,in1)*IN1+c(in2,in2)*IN2+c(in3,in3)*IN3+c(in4,in4)*IN4
   illness =~ NA*IL1+c(il1,il1)*IL1+c(il2,il2)*IL2+c(il3,il3)*IL3+c(il4,il4)*IL4+c(il5,il5)*IL5
   
   ISIg =~ NA*injury + c(IN,IN)*injury + c(IN,IN)*illness
   
   IN4~~IL5
   IL1~~IL2
  

  IN1 ~ c(iin1,iin1) * 1
  IN2 ~ c(iin2,iin2) * 1
  IN3 ~ c(iin3,iin3) * 1
  IN4 ~ c(iin4,iin4) * 1
  injury ~ c(IIN,IIN) * 1
  
  IL1 ~ c(iil1,iil1) * 1
  IL2 ~ c(iil2,iil2) * 1
  IL3 ~ c(iil3,iil3) * 1
  IL4 ~ c(iil4,iil4) * 1
  IL5 ~ c(iil5,iil5) * 1
  illness ~ c(IIL,IIL) * 1
  
  in1 == 4 - in2 - in3 - in4
  iin1 == 0 - iin2 - iin3 - iin4
 
  
  il1 == 5 - il2 - il3 - il4 - il5
  iil1 == 0 - iil2 - iil3 - iil4 - iil5
  
  
  IIN == 0 - IIL


  ISIg ~~ c(DVp11,DVp12)*ISIg


  ISIg ~ c(DVk11,DVk12)*1



  d := (DVk12 - DVk11) / ((217*DVp12 + 220*DVp11)/(217*220)^0.5)
   '

  fit.smmlanguage<-cfa(smmlanguage,EnglishGreek, group='Dataset',  estimator="MLM", 
               std.lv=FALSE)

  summary(fit.smmlanguage, fit=TRUE, standardized=TRUE)
```

According to a scalar invariance examination, I want to free the between group equality constraints of the intercepts of IN2 and IL4. However, I need to label them and apply the effect coding constraint at the same time (all works fine without effects-coding, but I want to use it). If I label them, I need to give the intercepts different labels for each group to release the between group constraints. However, if I do that, I cannot apply the effect.coding constraints, because I need to use the labels, and if I have different labels for each group, which one do I use? I tried using the (effect.coding = TRUE, group.equal = c(loadings,intercepts), group.partial = c("IN2 * 1", IL4 * 1) line on the 'cfa' command, but for some reason, it severely distorts the fit of the model, so I decided to do the full syntax myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the effects-coding constraint only with the anchor indicators (i.e., the ones that are equal / without DIF).

Conceptually, you could apply the effects-coding constraint separately per group, using each set of labels (like in the configural model).  However, when only one indicator (per factor) has different parameters in the partial-scalar model, then the effects-coding constraint actually implies equality anyway.  That is why the effects-coding constraint should only be applied to anchor indicators.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much for your time as always!